# How to load two pandas dataframe into hugginface's dataset object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to load the train and test data frame into the dataset object. The usual way to load a pandas dataframe into dataset object is:

```
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
```

My question is how to load train and test both pandas dataframe into the dataset?

for example if I have two dataframes:

```
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd
df_train = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
df_test = pd.DataFrame({"ab": [1, 2, 3]})
```

How to load these two frames?

Answer (score 11):

You are able to load both pandas dataframes into a dataset using `DatasetDict` and `Dataset.from_pandas()`. You can keep your train and test split by adding keys to to the DatasetDict.

```python
from datasets import Dataset, DatasetDict

import datasets
import pandas as pd


df_train = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
df_test = pd.DataFrame({"ab": [1, 2, 3]})

datasets_train_test = DatasetDict({
    "train": Dataset.from_pandas(df_train),
    "test": Dataset.from_pandas(df_test)
    })
```

which results in

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['a'],
        num_rows: 3
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['ab'],
        num_rows: 3
    })
})
```

You can use `concatenate_datasets()` to concatenate a list of datasets.

```
dataset_train = Dataset.from_pandas(df_train)
dataset_test = Dataset.from_pandas(df_test)
datasets_all_in_one = datasets.concatenate_datasets([dataset_train, dataset_test])
```

which results in

```
Dataset({
    features: ['a', 'ab'],
    num_rows: 6
})
```